# Package dependencies and include dirs

Tags: ros, catkin, build, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a **package1** which generates services via a Type1.srv file. These generated services are located in **<catkin_ws>/devel/include/package1/Type1.h**. This all works fine.

Now when I want a **package2** to also use the services generated in **package1** I follow the steps described [in here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/cpp_msg_dependencies.html).

Now when building I get the following error:

```
... fatal error: package1/Type1.h: No such file or directory
 #include "package1/Type1.h"
                                ^
compilation terminated.
```

Now it turns out **package1/Type1.h** is well generated and does lie in **devel/include/package1/Type1.h**.

So I output the content of **package1_FOUND, package1_INCLUDE_DIRS** and **catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS** from **package2**'s **CMakeLists.txt** and it reads:

```
package1_FOUND : 1
package1_INCLUDE_DIRS : /opt/ros/indigo/include/usr/include
catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS : /opt/ros/indigo/include/usr/include
```

I would expect to get **../devel/include** for these values, no?

Anyone knows what I am missing here? How can I let my system know about the include path to **devel/include**? I guess I do not have to set these includes by hand, do I?

Kind regards,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244034/package-dependencies-and-include-dirs/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2016-09-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-19**:
No, for headers generated from msgs the include paths should be added automatically. It would help if you could include the relevant `CMakeLists.txt` (please without all the comments).

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-09-19**:
Make sure you have the right dependencies listed in package.xml and CMakeLists.txt. If you don't have your package1 listed as a dependency, the include path will be wrong. As @gvdhoom points out, if you post them it would be easier for others to help you find what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The root of my problem actually lied in my use of orocos. Orocos actually requires to replace **catkin_package** by **orocos_generate_package()** and use **${USE_OROCOS_INCLUDE_DIRS}** in addition to **${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}**.

I already found CMake dirty (because of its lack of clear structure), then catkin added a layer of confusion with its needed redundancy, now I must admit the addition of the orocos build system requirements on top of the former two is a real pain.

Thanks for your help guys, you really helped!

---

Originally posted by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) with karma: 955 on 2016-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-21**:
I think you might be able to make some of this more clear and reduce layering by creating separate pkgs for msgs, services and the rest (ie: nodes).

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2016-09-21**:
You mean I should split my packages so that a single package does not define services (for instance) and nodes (or orocos components) at the same time, is that right?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-21**:
Yes.

That is a recommended practice anyway, as it allows users of your services or messages to depend just on your msg pkgs, instead of having to install everything. It would clearly separate your ROS API from your implementation.

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2016-09-21**:
This is very clear, thanks a lot!